# Format decimal value based on the scale

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do the following:

On my website I show products with nutritional information. The 'Total Fat' is a decimal (18,1 in SQL Server).

The wish of my client is that whenever the value is like '1.0', '2.0' etc. it must show just the number '1' or '2'.

If the value is '1.2' or '2.4' etc. nothing should happen and it should just show it as it is.

Is there a way to do this without all kind of string manipulation?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:#.#}", 1.0m); // outputs 1
String.Format("{0:#.#}", 1.5m); // outputs 1.5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
decimalNumber.ToString("0.#");
```

Example:

```
decimal num1 = 7.3M;
decimal num2 = 7.0M;

Console.WriteLine(num1.ToString("0.#")); //prints 7.3
Console.WriteLine(num2.ToString("0.#")); //prints 7
```